# Write out specific data from log

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I got a huge log in zipped files, i need to write out lines by specific data and if the line with the same contains XML message with the same sessionID will be written to the file to.

The log structure:

```
 2013-08-16 16:31:06,810 ( 122:            rogate) [98839276727]  INFO  -      UId:10453, GId:5422: new CONX started, Application Context: disconnected
 2013-08-16 16:31:34,210 ( 122:            rogate) [98839276727]  INFO  -      UId:32453, GId:1213: new CONX started, Application Context: disconnected
 2013-08-16 16:31:45,110 ( 122:            rogate) [98839276727]  INFO  -      UId:11453, GId:2133: new CONX started, Application Context: disconnected
 2013-08-16 16:31:45,729 (1093:               jms_con.cpp) [140561430333184] DEBUG  - Received XML TextMessage:
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><>
 <version>1</version>
 <sessionId>114532133</sessionId>
 <networkProtocolId>CAPv2</networkProtocolId>
 <trafficType>Forwarding</trafficType>
  <messages>
   <reportNotificationAck/>
 <superviseReq>
 <requestSequenceNr>0</requestSequenceNr>
 <time>60000</time>
 <releaseAfterTimeExpires>false</releaseAfterTimeExpires>
  <playWarningTone>false</playWarningTone>
 </superviseReq>
 <eventReportReq>
 <requestSequenceNr>1</requestSequenceNr>
 <events>
<routeSelectFailure monitorMode="Interrupt"/>
<busy monitorMode="Interrupt"/>
<noAnswer monitorMode="Interrupt">
  <noAnswerTimer>180000</noAnswerTimer>
</noAnswer>
<answer monitorMode="Notify"/>
<disconnectCalling monitorMode="Interrupt"/>
<disconnectCalled monitorMode="Interrupt"/>
<abandon monitorMode="Notify"/>
</events>
</eventReportReq>
<continueProcessing>
<requestSequenceNr>2</requestSequenceNr>
<moreEventsExpected>true</moreEventsExpected>
<interruptEventReceived>true</interruptEventReceived>
</continueProcessing>
2013-08-16 16:59:03,666 (1252:            capgw_main.cpp) [140561430333184]  INFO  - UId:57371, GId:7137: STAT_ISIG_PROCESSING: 0.001007.
2013-08-16 16:59:03,666 ( 888:  tcap_context_storage.cpp) [140561430333184] DEBUG  - UId:57371, GId:7137: updating the Last Appl. Access Time.
2013-08-16 16:59:03,666 ( 937:  tcap_context_storage.cpp) [140561430333184] DEBUG  - UId:57371, GId:7137: new Appl. message has different direction as previously stored one, calculating the response time.
2013-08-16 16:59:03,666 (1260:            capgw_main.cpp) [140561430333184] DEBUG  - UId:57371, GId:7137: TCAP Context Storage updated successfully (received iSig message).
2013-08-16 16:59:03,666 (1263:            capgw_main.cpp) [140561430333184]  INFO  - UId:57371, GId:7137: STAT_ISIG_RESP_TIME: 0.023346
2013-08-16 16:59:03,666 ( 767:  tcap_context_storage.cpp) [140561430333184] DEBUG  - UId:57371, GId:7137: updating the Last TCAP Access Time.
```

After the third line an XML message present with same sessionID as the line UiD+GiD. I need to write this lines to a new files, like this:

```
 2013-08-16 16:31:45,110 ( 122:            rogate) [98839276727]  INFO  -      UId:11453, GId:2133: new CONX started, Application Context: disconnected
 2013-08-16 16:31:45,729 (1093:               jms_con.cpp) [140561430333184] DEBUG  - Received XML TextMessage:
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><>
 <version>1</version>
 <sessionId>114532133</sessionId>
 <networkProtocolId>CAPv2</networkProtocolId>
 <trafficType>Forwarding</trafficType>
  <messages>
   <reportNotificationAck/>
 <superviseReq>
 <requestSequenceNr>0</requestSequenceNr>
 <time>60000</time>
 <releaseAfterTimeExpires>false</releaseAfterTimeExpires>
  <playWarningTone>false</playWarningTone>
 </superviseReq>
 <eventReportReq>
 <requestSequenceNr>1</requestSequenceNr>
 <events>
<routeSelectFailure monitorMode="Interrupt"/>
<busy monitorMode="Interrupt"/>
<noAnswer monitorMode="Interrupt">
  <noAnswerTimer>180000</noAnswerTimer>
</noAnswer>
<answer monitorMode="Notify"/>
<disconnectCalling monitorMode="Interrupt"/>
<disconnectCalled monitorMode="Interrupt"/>
<abandon monitorMode="Notify"/>
</events>
</eventReportReq>
<continueProcessing>
<requestSequenceNr>2</requestSequenceNr>
<moreEventsExpected>true</moreEventsExpected>
<interruptEventReceived>true</interruptEventReceived>
</continueProcessing>
```

Where a file named as XML message sessionID, like 114532133_something.txt and write this every two log messages into a new file.

Thanks for helping!

Edit:

Trying to do in a script with not so many sucess.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS=":|," }
FNR==NR && /INFO/ {
    a[$0,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10]++ ;
    next

}

END

{
    for (i in a) print i
}
```

Comment: Can you post 2 or more block of data?  It will help me to see how to break this up

Comment: I'm added some other lines. Just needed those lines where XML message presents. Where the sessionID as the same as UId+GId. And every this line+XML message printed in a new file and this text file named as sessionID_cpv.txt. Thanks

Comment: What would you like to have in the file?
Only the line with date info, the xml block?
Is there more than one xml block in your file to be repeated?

Comment: Yes there are more XML messages, but needed just those where the sessionID same as the UID+GId. It will be great that the files contains the whole line + XML message.

Comment: "Please write my program for me" is not an appropriate use of StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry. I'm just stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I have divided this into multiple tasks. It may be that someone can join all this together.

1- Find all Session ID form line containing INFO and store it to file **t1**

```
awk -F":|," 'FNR==NR && /INFO/ {a[$6$8]++;next} END {for (i in a) print i }' xml_file >t1
```

2- Remove all log lines (starting with 2013) and store it in **t2**

```
awk  '!/^2013/' xml_file >t2
```

3- Print every XML bulk if it does contain one of the ID found in step 1

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]++;next} FNR==1 {RS="</continueProcessing>"} { for (i in a) {if ($0~i) print}}'  t1 t2
```

I have assumed that all XML section do end with .  If that is not true, this will not work.

Comment: But i dont want to remove the log lines, just needed those where XML message present with the same session id, that the log line contains as UId+GId. And create every this (Log line+XML message) a new file named with sessionID_something.txt.

Comment: So you want all log lines + all xml bulk that are found with INFO in log line?  So just remove XML bluks that do not have log line with INFO

Comment: All log lines that contains INFO with XML message. Just these lines into new files. Every this log line+XML message into a new file, that file will be called as the XML message sessionID. For example: In the log i got a line with with UId + GId, for some of this logs got an XML message with number (UId+GId) as sessionID. I need to write out these two thing into a new file. Every log line where XML message present.